# Syntax Error: positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python

```
 ratings_list = [i.strip().split("::") for i in open(encoding="utf8", 'ratings.csv', 'r').readlines()]
```

---

```
Input In [4]
    ratings_list = [i.strip().split("::") for i in open(encoding="utf8", 'ratings.csv', 'r').readlines()]
                                                                                           ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

Comment: what is unclear in the error? Just move `encoding="utf8"` to the end

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
open('output.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
```

keyword-arguments like `encoding='utf-8'` (encoding is the keyword) must not be succeeded by positional arguments (which are assigned in the function call by the position in the parameter list).